# strange behavior when trying to swap two variables in python

Tags: python

I encounter the following code in how to think like a computer scientist, and it's a bit strange to me. Could anyone explain to me what is going on?
Here is how I tried to understand it.

(1): what the swap function does (more precisely, the (x,y)=(y,x)) is to swap the references of x and y.

(2): When the function swap(a,b) is called, it is passed by reference. That's to say, a and x will share the reference, y and b will share the reference.

(3): Based on (1) and (2), we only swap the references of x and y, and nothing has changed for a and b. That's why this swap function does not work.

Could anyone tell me whether this understanding is correct or not?

```
def swap(x, y):      # Incorrect version
     print("before swap statement: x:", x, "y:", y)
     (x, y) = (y, x)
     print("after swap statement: x:", x, "y:", y)

a = ["This", "is", "fun"]
b = [2,3,4]
print("before swap function call: a:", a, "b:", b)
swap(a, b)
print("after swap function call: a:", a, "b:", b)
```

Comment: You're swapping `x` and `y`, not `a` and `b`. This is not supposed to "do anything". Does that answer your question…?

Comment: This is about variable scope. `x, y` inside `swap` are local variables, so global `a, b` are unchanged.

Comment: Also, you can use `x,y = y,x` without the parentheses.

Comment: I do not think my question answered here. Why the function is not supposed to do "anything"? What is the relation between x and a, y and b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with saying that parameters are passed by reference in Python is that it's not completely accurate. It is very different than what happens in C++, for instance.

When you define a variable, you essentially tell Python that its name is currently bound to some value. That values lives in the Python VM. When you do this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
```

Both `a` and `b` points to the same reference of `[1,2,3]`, which is why `a.append(4)` would also affect `b`. However, if you redefine `b` to a new value, you will notice that `a` is not affected:

```
b = "hello"
print(a) # [1,2,3]
```

When you did this, you did not modify the reference pointed by `b`. You simply told Python that while `b` used to point to `[1,2,3]`, it now points to `"hello"`. You never interacted with the object `[1,2,3]` in memory, only with the `b` name.

Inside your `swap` function, when you do `x, y = y, x`, you tell Python that the `x` name now points to the reference held by `y`, and vice versa. Notice however that the actual objects being referenced aren't swapped in memory. Outside your function, `a` and `b` still points to the same references, because you never actually interacted with the `a` and `b` names.

In pictures, this is what happens. Before:

[image: Before swapping]

After:

[image: After swapping]

Comment: Wonderful explanation!